# Sync data on computers with different OS but without an Internet connection

Tags: hard-drive, memory, sync, dropbox, google-drive

I have three computers in following status:

1. A pc at working place with Windows XP os.
2. A laptop at home with Ubuntu os.
3. A laptop at home with Windows 7 os.

also I haven't any internet connection for using tools such as Dropbox or Google Drive. I find several tools such as Unison or JFileSync for sync by a external hard drive or usb stick.

I have two questions:

1. Has anyone more suggestion or idea for solve this requirement?
2. Are there more free and power tools for my situation?

Comment: Have you tried http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15155 ? It doesn't support Ubuntu though

Comment: So, you've found Unison. Have you tried it already? It should do what you want.

Comment: @AbhishekGirish No, because I want install on three operation system.

Comment: @slhck still no.

Comment: "no", how exactly? Have you tried it? What aspects doesn't it cover? If you could expand your question to mention that, we could probably help you more.

Comment: @slhck I wanted before choose any tools confer with expert in this site.

Comment: Asking for software recommendations is considered *not constructive*. I'm sure there are experts who can help you, but you will have to do a little research, or, at the very least, please *try for yourself*. If you don't succeed, once you get stuck, we can surely help you.

Comment: @slhck I research several days and found above result but want know expert suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I'm a big fan a NAS systems.  I know you can't connect to the internet but if you have a home network many NAS solutions will just plug right into your router these days.  If you've never heard of NAS it stands for Network Attached Storage, and it's acts like a standalone disk(s) on your network.  How you "mount" it depends on the OS but you should be able to make it happen on all three platforms with pretty much any NAS.

If you don't have a home network and need a solution like JFileSync check out this page for an overview of what's available:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_synchronization_software

Comment: The OP has one computer sitting at work, the others at home. A NAS wouldn't help him, I guess.

Comment: Thanks, really my main problem is between office and home computers. However I will read above post.

Comment: just noticed that...  one of these days I'll figure out how to read

Comment: some NAS systems support VPN, but that could be tricky depending on your network set up at work. not to mention the fact you have no internets :(